# Disposing a RequireJS Required Class

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, requirejs, singlepage, js-amd

Im using requireJS to dynamically load JS modules in my html5 single page web application. Im just wanting to know whether I should dispose of the requireJS loaded modules once i have finished with them (so the garbage collector can clean them up)? And if so than how do you dispose a required module from requireJS?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to undefine a module:

> There is a global function, requirejs.undef(), that allows undefining
>   a module. It will reset the loader's internal state to forget about
>   the previous definition of the module. However, it will not remove the
>   module from other modules that are already defined and got a handle on
>   that module as a dependency when they executed. So it is really only
>   useful to use in error situations when no other modules have gotten a
>   handle on a module value, or as part of any future module loading that
>   may use that module. See the errback section for an example. If you
>   want to do more sophisticated dependency graph analysis for undefining
>   work, the semi-private onResourceLoad API may be helpful.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#undef

I'm not too sure on the internals but in my usage of the lib I've not found it necessary to do any manual clean up of modules.